# Perl: How to simultaneously access mutliple nonconsecutive elements in an array?

Tags: perl

The array I want to query does not change during execution:

```
my @const_arr=qw( a b c d e f g);
```

The input is a string containing the indices I want to access, for example:

```
my $str ="1,4";
```

Is there something (besides iterating over the indices in `$str`) along the lines of  `@subarray = @const_arr[$str]` that will result in `@subarray` containing `[b,e]`
?

Comment: And to answer my own question..
@subarray=@const_arr[eval($str)]

Comment: Using `eval` to parse your input is overkill, and opens the door to security issues.  `split` is a better tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Choroba, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: `my @const_arr=` **`(`** `a,b,c,d,e,f` **`)`** `;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the indices are in a string, you can split the string to get them:

```
@array    = qw(a b c d e);
$indices  = '1,4';
@subarray = @array[split /,/, $indices];
print "@subarray\n";
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it kept the 'my's and variable names from the question.

Comment: @hochgurgler: Well, I cannot use the name "const" for something that is not a constant :-)

Comment: @choroba, One could argue that using the name "@const_arr" *makes* it a constant. (Just not one enforced by the compiler.)

Answer (score 4):

An array slice will do this:

```
@const_arr=qw(a b c d e);
@subarray=(@const_arr)[1,4];
print "@subarray"'
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue of how to get from the string "1,4" to the list (1,4)

Answer (score 4):

```
my @const_arr = qw(a b c d e f);  # the {...} creates a hash reference, 
                                  # not what you wanted

my $str = "1,4";

my @idx = split /,/ => $str;

my @wanted = @const_arr[@idx];
```

or in one line:

```
my @wanted = @const_arr[split /,/ => $str];
```

Answer (score 3):

`@const_arr` should initiate like this:

```
my @const_arr = qw(a b c d e f);
```

then you can access to 1 and 4 element by:

```
@const_arr[1,4]
```